# Sign in in a website using the terminal

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm trying to sign in in a website using this command: wget --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'login_email=aaaaaaa&login_password=123456' http://aaaaa.com/index.php

but it doesn't work. Is there another command to sign in in a website automatically?

Thank you a lot for answering me

Answer (score 1):

`wget` is intended to fetch (=get) files (it is a "non-interactive network downloader" as stated in the man page.

You need a text based web browser, such as [links2 [image: Install links2]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/links2) (my choice) or [lynx [image: Install lynx]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lynx), or [w3m [image: Install w3m]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/w3m).